# Ubuntu login loop and bad interpreter everytime i call sudo

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to install wireshark when I accidentally had to restart my computer. Now I am stucked in a infinite login loop in Ubuntu. I tried to do something from the bash but every time I try to run a `sudo` command, as `sudo su` it gets:

```
-bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/non/python3: bad interpreter: permission denied.
```

I tried to change the permission to that but it does not work.

EDIT: 

i solved by entering in recovery mode as root user and `sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/command-not-found` and even `sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/python3`. I tried everything possible, and i dont even know why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo dpkg -i python2.7-miminal*.deb
sudo dpkg -i python2.7*.deb
```

Comment: It doesnt work because everytime i type sudo it gets that error message. I cant understand why, i cant even do sudo apt-get update.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I have added export `$PATH="~/bin" as last line in ~/.bash_profile.`

I **solved** it by removing the line after entering into `tty2` command line using `"ctrl + alt + F3"` and all commands like `"ls, cd, nano"` where available as `"/bin/ls, /bin/cd, /bin/nano"`.

Using command "/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile" I changed the file content and now it's working normally.